# Passing vb.net object byref to unmanaged code

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, marshalling, marshalbyrefobject

I am rasing an event from managed **vb.net** code which is being handled in unmanaged **vc++** code. Below is the code line :

```
Dim pCALMarkups as Object
RaiseEvent RequestEISData(nOrdinal, pCALMarkups, eMarkupCreateSecurity, eMarkupModifySecurity, eMarkupDeleteSecurity, sUserNameSecurity)
```

**pCALMarkups** object is being passed as reference and will be *initialized* in unmanaged vc++ code.
Below is the declaration of the event in VB.NET:

```
 Public Event RequestEISData(ByVal nOrdinal As Short, <[In](), [Out]()> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)> ByRef pCALMarkups As Object, ByRef eMarkupCreateSecurity As Short, ByRef eMarkupModifySecurity As Short, ByRef eMarkupDeleteSecurity As Short, ByRef sUserNameSecurity As String)
```

Below is the function which is handling this event in **VC++**

```
 void __stdcall OnRequestEISDataViewer(short nOrdinal, 
                                     IDispatch **pMarkups, 
                                     short *eMarkupCreateSecurity,
                                     short *eMarkupModifySecurity,
                                     short *eMarkupDeleteSecurity,
                                     BSTR *sUserNameSecurity)
{  CCALPageMarkups* pCalMarkups = new CComObject <CCALPageMarkups>;
   // CCALPageMarkups is a class declared in vc++ code
   // Some code for initializing pCalMarkups 
  *pMarkups = pCalMarkups;  //last line of code in this function 
}
```

During debugging of the code I am able to step into the **OnRequestEISDataViewer** function , everything inside that function is being executed without any error, but when control comes out of the function after executing last line it is showing the below mentioned error :

*"Managed Debugging Assistant 'InvalidVariant' has detected a problem in 'D:\Shared Folder\Workman code\UI\bin\WorkMan.exe'.
Additional Information: An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss"*

So how do I strong type or Marshal **pCALMarups** object in **VB.NET** code so that this error will be resolved ? or Do I have to change vc++ code ?
Any suggestion is appreciated.